# Silhouette score significance: what is a significant increase in silhouette score?

Tags: statistical-significance, clustering, validation

I'm aware a silhouette score ranges from -1 to 1. But what can be considered a significant increase? 0.1 to 0.2 (because 100%) or 0.5 to 0.6?

Obviously higher is better, but is there some measure of significance when it comes to silhouette scores?

Comment: Could you provide a reference to "silhouette scores", it's not a term I've seen before.

Comment: It's you who decides. Typically, mean silhouette over 0.6 is considered a "good" clustering solution.

Comment: @MatthewDrury https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the scores are bounded by 1, I would consider going from 0.1 to 0.2 a 1-(0.8/0.9) about 11% improvement only, whereas 0.5 to 0.6 is 20% improvement on this scale (20% reduction in "error" from the optimum).

However, I would **avoid the use of "significant"** unless you can relate this to statistical testing!

Beware that Silhouette etc. **should not be used to compare different methods** because they have a bias. Silhouette is a heuristic tool to see whether you have chosen parameters reasonably, and can thus be okay to use when having to choose e.g. k in k-means. But an argument like "k-means is better than HAC because we had a significantly higher silhouette score on all our data sets" will likely be nonsense, because of bias towards one clustering algorithm or another.

Comment: The first paragraph is weird to me. Can you explain? And where did you see "error" notion in silhouette index?

Comment: Silhouette doesn't have a notion of error, but you can  compute the "gain" twoards the optimum silhouette of 1. That makes more sense than considering 0.1 to 0.2 a 100% increase.

Comment: Can you provide insight into your second statement ? Since the Silouhette only uses the partitions and the dissimilarity function I don't see where the bias can come from ? E.g. two runs of kmeans should be comparable, no ? kmeans vs kmedoids should work too ?

Comment: Compare silhouette with Euclidean distance and Manhattan distance, and you get different results. Furthermore, it clearlyprefers centroid-based and convex clusterings over e.g. DBSCAN *by design*.